# How to use promise in while(JavaScript/Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, synchronous

I'm trying to execute repeatly multiple processes in sequence by using promise and while (JavaScript/Node.js).
However, the promise function is not executed (i.e., all console.log() is never displayed).

Why is the promise function never executed in the while?

Also, how can I display the some console.log() repeatedly in sequence?

```
var count = 0;
while(count < 5) {
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func1()...');
      resolve('OK');
    });
  })
  .then(function(value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func2()...');
      resolve('OK');
    });
  })
  .then(function (value) {
    console.log('func3()...');
    count++;
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `count++;` executes asynchronously, your `while` just keeps looping forever.

Comment: You can't. Look into Promise.all or async/await syntax.

Comment: @tkausl
The promise function was executed by writing count ++ after the promise function. Thank you.
However, each console.log () is executed 5 times in succession. I want to run like this. 
console.log (func1 () ...) → console.log (func2 () ...) → console.log (func3 () ...) → console.log (func1 () ...) → ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then()` still remains an asynchronous callback, see the order of messages here:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("got resolved"));
console.log("got here");
```

One thing you can do is wrap the code into an [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
async function test(){
  var count = 0;
  while(count < 5) {
    await Promise.resolve()
    .then(function () {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('func1()...');
        resolve('OK');
      });
    })
    .then(function(value) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('func2()...');
        resolve('OK');
      });
    })
    .then(function (value) {
      console.log('func3()...');
      count++;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening - in Javascript the event loop and source code you write is executed in one thread. It means that if this one thread is blocked by some work, nothing else is executed.
It works quite straightforward - event loop takes one event (code you show) and it processes ALL synchronous part and it pushes any asynchronous things (the promise chain) to event loop to be executed later.

The issue is this:

```
var count = 0;
while(count < 5) {
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(
  // some promise chain...
}
```

The `while` is catched in never ending loop, as all the synchronous part is that it push this Promise chain in event loop and then starting again. The `count` is never changed in this context.

The best for you is to use `async/await` which solves exactly what you want without need deeply understand Node.js

The other option is to use recursion

```
function promiseChain() {
  return Promise.resolve()
  .then(function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func1()...');
      resolve('OK');
    });
  })
  .then(function(value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func2()...');
      resolve('OK');
    });
  })
  .then(function (value) {
    console.log('func3()...');
    count++;
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

recursivelyExecute(promise, count) {
  if (count > 5) {
    return;
  }
  count++;
  return promise.then(() => recursivelyExecute(promiseChain(), count+1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the nice proposal. 
However, this code gives an error in recursivelyExecute (promise, count) {}.
(error: Unexpected token { )
Why?

Comment: This code could use some cleanup. The use of ‘count’ as a shadowed variable passed as an arg is confusing if this is just example code, and broken if meant to be executable code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 0;
while(count < 5) {
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func1()...');
      resolve('OK');
    });
  })
  .then(function(value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func2()...');
      resolve('OK');
    });
  })
  .then(function (value) {
    console.log('func3()...');
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the promise function was executed.
However, each console.log () is executed 5 times in succession.
I want to run like this.
console.log (func1 () ...) → console.log (func2 () ...) → console.log (func3 () ...) → console.log (func1 () ...) → ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Promise.all()` along with `async.eachSeries` for looping. For this you need to install [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) then do the following:

```
const async = require('async');
var count = [...Array(5).keys()];
async.eachSeries(count, (c, next) => {
  Promise.all([
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func1()...');
      resolve('OK');
    }), 
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      console.log('func2()...');
      resolve('OK');
    })]).then(function (values) {
    console.log('func3()...');
    next();
  });
}, (err) => {
  console.log("here we done");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, almost the answer I want. However, the results are as follows: console.log ('func1 () ...') → console.log ('func2 () ...') → console.log ('func3 () ...') → console.log ('func3 () ... ') → console.log (' func3 () ... ') → ...
I want to do the following: console.log ('func1 () ...') → console.log ('func2 () ...') → console.log ('func3 () ...') → console.log ('func1 () ... ') → console.log (' func2 () ... ') → console.log (' func3 () ... ') → ...

Comment: I see that you found the answer. I just fixed it and updated my answer for any future person searching for the solution.